# Unicorn emulator: find out if register is undefined

Tags: x86, emulation

Maybe I am stupid, but I really dont see anything in their documentation. 
Say I emulate this code

```
mov eax, 1
mov ecx, 2
```

Then I can get the result  like so:

```
int rr;
uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_ECX, &rr);
```

Now I have to wonder - what happens when I read from an undefined register, say ESI?

```
uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_ESI, &rr);
```

Answer is rr == 0. But how can I detect that this register is undefined, rather than '0'?

Answer (score 1):

an emulator requires your input to emulate if you didn't define something you would obviously get what it was initialized with

apparently unicorn starts initialized with 0 for all registers it seems

src to read all registers using the given api

```
:\>cat testumu.cpp
#include "unicorn.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"unicorn.lib")
#define REG_NUMS 9
void main (void) {
    uc_engine *uc;
    int regs[REG_NUMS]  = {
        UC_X86_REG_EAX,UC_X86_REG_EBX,UC_X86_REG_ECX,
        UC_X86_REG_EDX,UC_X86_REG_EBP,UC_X86_REG_ESP,
        UC_X86_REG_ESI,UC_X86_REG_EDI,UC_X86_REG_EIP
    };
    int bugs[REG_NUMS] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    void *vals[REG_NUMS];
    for(int i =0; i<REG_NUMS;i++) {
        vals[i] = &bugs[i];
    }
    printf("values before reading\n\n");
    for(int i =0 ; i< REG_NUMS; i++) {
        printf("%x\t%x\n" , regs[i],*(int *)vals[i]);
    }
    if((uc_open(UC_ARCH_X86, UC_MODE_32, &uc)) == UC_ERR_OK) {
        uc_reg_read_batch(uc,regs,vals,9);
    }
    printf("values after reading\n\n");
    for(int i =0 ; i< REG_NUMS; i++) {
        printf("%x\t%x\n" , regs[i],*(int *)vals[i]);
    }
}
```

compiled and linked with vc2017 community cmd prompt for x86

```
:\>cl /nologo /Zi /W4 /analyze /Ox testumu.cpp /link /release
testumu.cpp

:\>
```

results of compiled executable

```
:\>testumu.exe
values before reading

13      1
15      2
16      3
18      4
14      5
1e      6
1d      7
17      8
1a      9
values after reading

13      0
15      0
16      0
18      0
14      0
1e      0
1d      0
17      0
1a      0

:\>
```

Comment: what i want to find out is essentially if a given emulated asm snipped modified/set a register. For that I could set all the register to some magic value and then check after emulation which ones differ. I am wondering if there is a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Unicorn only supports concrete values in registers. 
You could cheat your way around this by doing two runs with two sets of magic values.

But what you really want is a symbolic execution framework like [angr](http://angr.io). There registers can be undefined after execution or even contain expression trees like old_ebx*2+1.